# Encounter TypeError with casperjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, casperjs, spawn

when I execute casperjs, it throws an TypeError:

```
#casperjs test.js 

child_process.js:936
  var r = this._handle.spawn(options);
                       ^
TypeError: Bad argument
    at ChildProcess.spawn (child_process.js:936:24)
    at exports.spawn (child_process.js:736:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs:22:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

and without test.js it throws same error:

```
# casperjs

child_process.js:936
  var r = this._handle.spawn(options);
                       ^
TypeError: Bad argument
    at ChildProcess.spawn (child_process.js:936:24)
    at exports.spawn (child_process.js:736:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs:22:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

casperjs was installed with following command refer to http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/installation.html#installing-from-npm:

```
$ npm install -g casperjs
```

thanks a lot in advance if any one can help on it.

Comment: might be a dumb question but do you have phantomjs and python installed? while you can install from npm, its not really a nodejs app and runs on top of those

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the issue came from phantomjs:

```
#phantomjs hello.js

child_process.js:936
  var r = this._handle.spawn(options);
                       ^
TypeError: Bad argument
    at ChildProcess.spawn (child_process.js:936:24)
    at exports.spawn (child_process.js:736:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs:22:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

after reinstall phantomjs the issue was gone:

```
npm install -g phantomjs
```

A CDN site:

```
PHANTOMJS_CDNURL=http://cnpmjs.org/downloads npm install -g phantomjs
```

Both phantomjs and casperjs goes right:

```
# phantomjs -v
1.9.8
# phantomjs hello.js 
Hello, world!
#casperjs test.js               
百度一下，你就知道
```

The root cause seems to be that a broken phantomjs was installed before, when executed phantomjs it source the broken version.

Thanks the guys upping the questions. 
Wish this expierence will help others.

Best Regards
-Radon

Comment: Another option is to use `npm install phantomjs --phantomjs_cdnurl=http://cnpmjs.org/downloads` if you're working with a shell script and want it all in one place.